# How to show websites in facebook after pressing "use app"

Tags: facebook

How is it possible to show websites in facebook after pressing "Use app" in pages? I knew it was possible before using page tabs, but now they changed the rules so that you need over 2000 followers for that page. I am looking for something like this:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's still available, but like you said yourself it now requires the page to have at least 2000 followers. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs/

Comment: Yes and i was looking for an alternative for people having below 2000 followers? Is it not possible anymore?